# In Angular 2+, how can i keep the received data between changing views easily

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question about how to keep some already received data between changing views (components). 
Let's suppose that: The user is filtering some products that are returned from the API, and after, the user is click on specific product to see 'single page product'. I want when is going back on previous page to have all the products already searched without make another request to API for them.

Please advice! Thank you!

PS: I already tried to save them into localstorge, but i think is not good practice.

Comment: Have a look at storing the data in a service.

Comment: since you are already on angular, why not just use rxjs to cache your data?

Comment: Create an observable to which you will put the data obtanied from API and then just subscribe to that observable where ever you need in your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best for you is to use a Service to share the data between every component. Like this, you'll have a place where all the data are stored and you can query your service to get this data.

You have some infirmation here:

[]
http://www.learnangularjs.net/global-data-sharing-in-angular-4.php
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i will try to implement a service that storing the data. I will use first link that you gave me.